# Why can't I reuse any UITableView cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` showing over 50 custom-designed cells. The table shows ok, but if I scroll the table, no cells ever get reused. Instead my app just keeps loading new cells all the time, which is very slow on my iPhone 3.

What could be causing this problem? Here's a code snipped from my `UITableViewSource.GetCell()` method

```
var dequeuedCell=tableView.DequeueReusableCell (identifier);

    //try to reuse a previously recycled cell, create a new one if none exists
    var cell = (ITimeEntryTableCell)dequeuedCell;
    if (cell == null)
    {
        //load a new cell using the XIB file definition
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib (identifier, tableViewController, null);
        cell = tableViewController.DurationCell;
        tableViewController.DurationCell = null;

    }
```

Thanks,

Adrian

**Edit:** Please note that I am using Monotouch, not objective C...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the cell identifier in your xib file? If this is not set, your cells won't be dequeued.

Comment: In case anybody was confused like me: in the designer it is called 'Restoration ID' and not 'Identifier'.

Comment: @Zerga no it isn't. Restoration ID is about state restoration. The identifier is the correct field to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works perfectly -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell   = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cell1" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.oneMessage;
        self.oneMessage = nil;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE:** for monotouch, try this -

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(this._cellIdentifier);

    myTableViewCell mycell = null;
    if (cell == null)
    {
        mycell = new myTableViewCell();
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("RootViewController", _controller, null);
        _controller.myTableCell = new myTableViewCell();
        mycell = _controller.myTableCell;
        cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, this._cellIdentifier);
    }
    else
    {
      mycell = (myTableViewCell)cell;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure it does, but I am using Monotouch, so I can't just copy and paste it. Feel free to let me know if you see any problems with the code I pasted in my OP though.

Comment: The Monotouch code you posted uses the same approach as my code. But where is the problem with my code? That's what I'd like to know.

Comment: are you sure the identifier is properly set? as such i dont see any problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

In the interface, declare: `TableViewCell * aCell`, and try using this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
  static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
  TableViewCell * cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil]; // hooks up cell for us.
    cell = aCell;
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I doesn't really help, since I am using Monotouch, so I can't even read, not to mention understand the finer nuances of the code you posted... Feel free to let me know if you see any problem with my code though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "identifier" is an NSString, as this could be used as a token internally, instead of a a string-content comparison.

So:

NSString identifier = new NSString ("myID");